# Packaged Custom Metadata Type Records Not Editable Once Deployed Even Though They Are Public

Tags: custom-metadata

I have a managed package which has a custom metadata type. My package has default records in that custom metadata type. The custom metadata has been set to have a visibility of **Public**.

[image: Custom Metadata Type Configuration]

Also, those records that have been created have been set to NOT be a protected component.

[image: Custom Metadata Record]

But, when I deploy the package to a sandbox I am not able to change the defaulted values. (I am a Sys Admin)

[image: Cannot Change Cusotm Metadata Value!!]

What am I doing wrong? I was under the impression that if the custom metadata type was public and the records are not protected then anybody should be able to update the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one more variable called ***Field Manageability*** on the fields. It has three options

- Only the package developer (via package upgrade)
- Any user with the Customize Application permission (managed package upgrades won't overwrite the value)
- No one

If you choose **only the package developer** then you can only edit it. Similarly if you chose **No one** then no one can edit it.

Comment: yes. This looks to be it. Both the fields are set to "Upgradable" and should read "Subscriber editable"

Comment: Is there a way of changing this now that the package has been released? Or am I stuck with two fields I can no longer use?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_req_managed_pkgs.htm&type=5. You cannot check here if you released it.